# Printing php variables in html

Tags: php, html

I've been tying myself in knots a bit trying to figure out how to print a couple of PHP variables into some HTML.  I just can't seem to get the single or double quotes correct.

I am pulling images from the 500px API and I want to render them into a bootstrap carousel.  The variables I want to use are `$photo->name` (which I have put in between the heading tags below and `$photo->url` which I want to put in instead of the placehold.it url.    Everything I have tried gives me an **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE error** however.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php           
      $i = 0;      
      $len = count($obj);
      foreach ($obj->photos as $photo){

        if ($i==0) {
          print '<div class="item active">
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One');">
                    </div>
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>$photo->name</h1>
                  </div>
                  </div>';
        } else {
          print "hello 2";
        }
        $i++;
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows you your error. You should use a decent text editor or IDE to avoid these issues.

Comment: Most mainstream browsers also have an error console in the developer menu(or as an add-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, using "echo", including:

```
$world = "world";

#If you wrap your statement in double-quotes, then:
echo "Hello $world, nice to meet you.";

#If you wrap your echo statement in single-quotes, then:
echo 'Hello '.$world.', nice to meet you.';
```

So, you might consider changing your code to:

```
<?php 

  $url = 'http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One';
  $i = 0;      
  $len = count($obj);

  foreach ($obj->photos as $photo){

    if ($i==0) {

      print '<div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(\''.$url.'\');">
                </div>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>'.$photo->name.'</h1>
              </div>
              </div>';

    } else {

      print "hello 2";

    }

    $i++;

  }
```

?>

Comment: thanks Josh.  That works when I escape the single quotes when defining the background image url.  However I can't then seem to replace the background image url       <?php           
          $i = 0;      
          $len = count($obj);
          foreach ($obj->photos as $photo){
            
            if ($i==0) {
              print '<div class="item active">
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(\''$photo->image_url '&amp;text=Slide One\');">
                        </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php           
          $i = 0;      
          $len = count($obj);
          foreach ($obj->photos as $photo){

            if ($i==0) {
              print '<div class="item active">
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(\'http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One\');">
                        </div>
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>'.$photo->name.'</h1>
                      </div>
                      </div>';
            } else {
              print "hello 2";
            }
            $i++;
          }
      ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Abhik.  But how do I change style="background-image:url(\'http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One\') to style="background-image:url(\'$photo->image_url&amp;text=Slide One\')?

Comment: You can do as                                         style="background-image:url(\' '.$photo->image_url.'&amp;text=Slide One\')

Answer (score 0):

```
..."background-image:url(\'http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One\')"...
```

Use \ to escape quatition

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` and paste html5 code between double quotes. Example:

```
echo "<div id='mydiv'>$phpvar</div>";
```

or concatenate vars with dots:

```
    echo "<div id='mydiv'>".$phpvar."</div>";
```

Sometimes the error depends on single or double quotes.

---

Have fun! (:

Answer (score 0):

You are having an escaping issue with strings, please observe the following examples:

```
$variable = 'my string';

echo $variable ; // my string
echo '$variable '; // $variable
echo "$variable "; // my string

$variable = 'my st'ring'; // ERROR
$variable = 'my st\'ring'; // escaped properly

echo $variable ; // my st'ring
echo '$variable '; // $variable
echo "$variable "; // my st'ring
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php           
      $i = 0;      
      $len = count($obj);
      foreach ($obj->photos as $photo){

        if ($i==0) {
          print "<div class='item active'>
                    <div class='fill' style='background-image:url(\"http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One\");'>
                    </div>
                  <div class='carousel-caption'>
                    <h1>$photo->name</h1>
                  </div>
                  </div>";
        } else {
          print "hello 2";
        }
        $i++;
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a variable to print or echo, you must close the quotes and add a point at the start and the end. For example:

```
<?php
     $and = "and";
     echo "Hello ".$and." how are you?"; //prints Hello and how are you
?>
```

**edit:** not I noticed that you have a quotes between `url()`. The PHP thinks that the string stops there. You must add a left-slash: `\` before it if you want that the next letter after it will be a part of the string. for example:

```
<?php
    echo "My teacher said "You are not listening!"."; // Even SO's editor thinks that "You are not listening!" isn't a part of the string and adds a color. It will return an erro.
    // the right way is:
    echo "My teacher said \"You are not listening!\"."; // Here you can see that the editor doesn't adds color to whatever in the quotes because it know that is is a part of the string. It prints My teacher said "You are not listening!".
?>
```

in your case:

```
<?php           
      $i = 0;      
      $len = count($obj);
      foreach ($obj->photos as $photo){

        if ($i==0) {
          print '<div class="item active">
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(\'http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One\');">
                    </div>
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>'.$photo->name.'</h1>
                  </div>
                  </div>';
        } else {
          print "hello 2";
        }
        $i++;
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: With double-quotes the variable is parsed anyway, concatenation isn't necessary

Comment: @DamienPirsy True, but is just starting in programming then it is better not to complicate it. First he needs to learn the usual way that works always.